# call WCF Service from SSL Enabled website

Tags: wcf

how can i call service from a ssl enabled website to a WCF service with basicHTTPBinding.

i am getting the error

The requested service, 'http://10.5.1.111/HRMSService/VehicleMaintenance/VehicleMaintenance.svc/test' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service, 'http://10.5.1.111/HRMSService/VehicleMaintenance/VehicleMaintenance.svc/test' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the correct bindings in Web.config?